# The normalizer of a $p$ sylow subgroup is itself

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

By the orbit-stabilizer theorem since the action is transitive then an orbit $\{gPg^{-1}: g\in G\} =n_p$ is equal to the number of $p$ sylow subgroups in a group $|G|=p^{\alpha}s$ with $(p^\alpha,s)=1$ and we get that $$|G/Stab_G(P)|=|G/\{g\in G: gPg^{-1}=P\}|=\frac{p^\alpha s}{|N_G(P)|}=n_p \text{ with } \begin{cases} n_p\equiv 1\mod{p} \\ n_p\mid s \end{cases}$$

The second condition on $n_p$ implies that $|N_G(P)|=p^\beta$ for some $\beta\le\alpha$

The first condition seems imply that $|N_G(P)|=p^\alpha\implies\beta=\alpha$

I'm not sure where I'm going with this but I'd like to know what characterizes a group that acts transitively/not transitively...

Comment: The statement that any two Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ are conjugate in $G$ is logically equivalent to the statement that the conjugation action of $G$ on its set of Sylow $p$-subgroups is transitive.

Comment: The transitivity of action on p-Sylow subgroups is one part of Sylow's theorem. As the action is by conjugation, this means any two p-Sylow subgroups are conjugate.

Comment: Ok but do you agree that the normalizer of a $p$-sylow subgroup is always itself? Because $|N_G(P)|=p^\alpha$ and $P\subset N_G(P)$

Comment: No, that is nonsense. The cyclic group of order $6$ is a counterexample.

Comment: How do you get that the order of $N_G(P)$ must be a power of $p$?

Answer (score 1):

The second condition implies that $\lvert N_G (P) \rvert = p^\alpha\left(\dfrac{s}{n_p}\right)$.
This does not imply that $\lvert N_G (P) \rvert$ is a power of the prime $p$.
What it does imply, however (since $\gcd (p^\alpha, s) = 1$), is that the highest power of $p$ that divides the integer $\lvert N_G (P) \rvert$ is $p^\alpha$.

P.S. The correct relationship between a $p$-Sylow subgroup $P$ of $G$ and its normaliser is that $[G:N_G (P)] = n_p$.
There is a bijection between all conjugates of $P$ (i.e. all the $p$-Sylow subgroups of $G$) and the left cosets of $N_G (P)$.
The bijection is $gPg^{-1} \mapsto gN_G (P)$.